# Not able to filter data in Composer Rest Server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to utilize the filter functionality of GetAll rest call in Composer Rest Server. For example in an asset named Order I want to fetch only orders related to User1. I gave {"User":"User1"} in filter textbox and clicked get all but still I am getting all the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the `where` clause

eg

`{where: {"UserId":"User1"}}` should work - or on the REST API itself

```
/api/Orders?filter[where][userId]=User1
```

etc

see more examples here :

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--filters-loopback

and here (loopback filter syntax and methods)

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html

Comment: Its working fine for the all the fields except the ones which have reference. For eg. if in an asset am giving reference of a participant like --> User user. I am not able to filter data. Is there any other syntax for that ?

Comment: I used http://xxx.xx.xx:3000/api/Orders?filter[where][userId]=[resource:org.acme.biznet.User#User1]  but no luck

Comment: I've used `curl -g -X GET 'http://localhost:3000/api/User?filter={"where":{"UserId":"resource:org.acme.biznet.User%23T01"},"include":"resolve"}' ` and it worked for me. Note that %23 is the ascii for '#' (using CURL) and -g is not to interpret braces (and T01 is my User id FYI).

Comment: also this works `curl -g -X GET 'http://localhost:3000/api/Commodity?filter[include]=resolve&filter[where][UserId]=resource:org.acme.biznet.User%23T01' `  (ie non-stringified JSON filter method) (again, %23 is substitution for the '#' symbol )

Comment: Two other non-resolve examples `{where: {"UserId":"resource:org.acme.biznet.Orders%23User1"}}` (stringified) and `filter[where][UserId]=resource:org.acme.biznet.User%23User1`  (non-stringified) so `http://xxx.xx.xx:3000/api/Orders?filter[where][UserId]=resource:org.acme.biznet.User%23User1` should work  (and in my case the field is `UserId` )